# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have a problem with a code of mine. I quite new to this, so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to write code, which runs through a data set and selects the data which is between a interval. For example, 300-301. The problem is that my current code, comes up with a error saying that my "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.". I want my loop to run through my dataset and find the data which is between 300-301, so 1 interval and store it in an array as a column. My code is below.

```
for n=300:305
impuls=[zeros];
for i=1:length(fmomentumTPC)
impuls=fmomentumTPC;
de/dx=fTPCsignal;
    if n<impuls(i) & impuls(i)<n+1
    impuls1(i)=impuls(i);
    de/dx1(i)=de/dx(i);
    end
P(:,n)=impuls1(find(impuls1~=0))';
end
```

thank in advance.

Comment: You must tag this with a language

Comment: It might also be valuable to use less confusing variable names.

Comment: I have @Tripp Kinetics tried to make it into less confusing names. The problem I´ m having, is that the number of data which lies in between 300-301 is not the same as 301-302, so the size of the array change inside the loop.

Comment: Use a cell array for P, which may contain arrays of different sizes in each cell.

Comment: Show us some runnable code. Someone would be able to help you then.